# Scheduled task in Spring Boot don't working

Tags: spring

I build simpy web api services application with Spring Boot, and I created some cron job service with  Scheduled task in Spring Boot, but dont working. I need to run this service every week day [Monday-Friday] at 12:00(on day).
That is a exmaple sheduling: `@Scheduled(cron="0 1 1 ? * *")`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include the @EnableScheduling in your config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Cron should be

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * MON-FRI")
```

Good example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have added the `@EnableScheduling` annotation in the configuration class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Check this https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/